# NavHostFragment отключить backstack

Tags: android, android-navigation-view, navigation

Подскажите, как отключить добавление фрагментов в backstack внутри navigation contoller'a.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533721/disable-adding-fragment-to-backstack-in-navigation-architecture-component

Comment: видел, немного не то